# How to read in values from forumales created with Xlsx writer into Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have excel spreadsheets generated with Xlsxwriter that contain formulas.  When I try to read the excel back into a pandas dataframe, it reads the value 0 instead of the calculated value of the formulas from the cells.  Is there a way to read in the actual calculated formula value into pandas?

Comment: Pandas reads the values from formulas normally. You sure there's no issue with the excel you are reading like, the calculated values are not pointing to some other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to read in the actual calculated formula value into pandas?

Not if the xlsx file was created using XlsxWriter.

From the XlsxWriter [FAQ](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html):

> **Q. Why do my formulas show a zero result in some, non-Excel applications?**
>
> Due to wide range of possible formulas and interdependencies between them XlsxWriter doesn’t, and realistically cannot, calculate the result of a formula when it is written to an XLSX file. Instead, it stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened.
>
> This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However, applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas, such as Excel Viewer, or several mobile applications, will only display the 0 results.

Comment: Thanks, my workaround was to mimic the logic from the formulas in pandas after reading in the other columns from thexlsxwriter created file.